# Procedure to insert into table and update another table

Tags: sql, oracle

I have looked everywhere for answers for this but nobody seems to know what the problem may be. So my procedure should add a row to the table INSÄTTNING. Some keys are reference keys. When the row has been inserted it should take P_BELOPP and subtract it with SALDO which is in another table called KONTO. The new amount should be added into that column and replace the old amount. My code looks like this so far:

```
create or replace procedure do_insättning(
p_radnr in insättning.radnr%type,
p_pnr in insättning.pnr%type,
p_knr in insättning.knr%type,
p_belopp in insättning.belopp%type,
p_datum in insättning.datum%type) 
as

begin
insert into insättning(radnr,pnr,knr) 
values(select radnr from kontoägare,select pnr from bankkund, select knr from 
konto);
insert into insättning(belopp,datum)
values(p_belopp,p_datum);
update konto 
set saldo = saldo - p_belopp
where knr = p_radnr; 
dbms_output.put_line('Saldo: '||''||saldo);
end;
```

I get ORA-00936: missing expression. I really dont understand where the expression is wrong.
Anybody got any suggestions?

Comment: first of all the common columns needed for the tables `kontoägare`, `bankkund` and `konto` among them.

Answer (score 1):

Your problem is a simple syntax error. There are no VALUES clause nor parentheses in the INSERT INTO ... SELECT construct. Also, the SELECT statement has to be a valid query.

Try this:

```
insert into insättning(radnr,pnr,knr) 
select t1.radnr 
      ,t2.pnr
      ,t3.knr
from       kontoägare t1
cross join bankkund   t2 
cross join konto.     t3
```

Probably you don't the result set to be a product. So you need to rewrite the FROM clause to use INNER JOIN clause with the appropriate conditions, and maybe a WHERE clause as well.

Comment: Im sorry sir but i didnt understand the part after the code :( I also got a new error that said "saldo must be declared"

Comment: Your INSERT statement is selecting values from **three tables**. But you have no joins or filters so the select statement will consist of **all the permutations** of those tables. If each table has two rows you will insert eight rows. [demo on db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_18&fiddle=24b00e766ab171fe7d8d9628460ba704) If you don't want that outcome you need to join the tables or filter the rows according to your business logic.

Comment: As for the new error, that means your table KONTO doesn't have a column called SALDO.